# Obter último registro de cada id em consulta sql com condição

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com dificuldades em obter o último registro de cada `id` em uma tabela do SQL Server.

```
select c.Serial,v.Descricao,v.Placa,v.Cor,v.AnoFabricacao,v.Chassi
c.DataHora,c.Endereco from [CheckPoint] c inner join Equipamento e on e.Serial= c.Serial
inner join Veiculo v on v.Codigo=e.CodigoVeiculo 
where v.Codigo in(44,45)
group by v.codigo,c.Serial,v.Descricao,v.Placa,v.Cor,v.AnoFabricacao,v.Chassi
,c.DataHora,c.Endereco
order by 
c.DataHora desc
```

Esta *query* esta me retornando os seguintes dados nessa ordem, gostaria que me mostrasse o registro mais atual de cada código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes colocar um exemplo, ou indicar qual o output que desejas obter?

Comment: Preciso Obter o registro mais atual de cada ID !ou seja a query tem que mi retornar 2 linhas!

Comment: Podes verificar em baixo, a minha resposta, para ver se devolve o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entendo que quando dizes o último registo pretendes aquele que tem data mais actual.

```
select c.Serial,
       v.Descricao,
       v.Placa,
       v.Cor,
       v.AnoFabricacao,
       v.Chassi,
       max(c.DataHora) as DataHora,
       c.Endereco 
from [CheckPoint] c 
inner join Equipamento e 
   on e.Serial= c.Serial
inner join Veiculo v 
   on v.Codigo=e.CodigoVeiculo 
where v.Codigo in(44,45)
group by v.codigo, c.Serial, v.Descricao, v.Placa, v.Cor, v.AnoFabricacao, v.Chassi, c.Endereco
order by c.DataHora desc
```

ou

```
select Serial,
       Descricao,
       Placa,
       Cor,
       AnoFabricacao,
       Chassi
       DataHora as DataHora,
       Endereco
from
(
    select c.Serial,
           v.Descricao,
           v.Placa,
           v.Cor,
           v.AnoFabricacao,
           v.Chassi
           c.DataHora as DataHora,
           c.Endereco,
           row_number() over (partition by v.Codigo order by c.DataHora desc) rn
    from [CheckPoint] c 
    inner join Equipamento e 
       on e.Serial= c.Serial
    inner join Veiculo v 
       on v.Codigo=e.CodigoVeiculo 
    where v.Codigo in(44,45)
    group by v.codigo, c.Serial, v.Descricao, v.Placa, v.Cor, v.AnoFabricacao, v.Chassi, c.DataHora, c.Endereco
    ) Resultados
    where rn = 1
    order by DataHora desc
```

Comment: Esse  exmplo a query nao esta correta ah alguns erros

Comment: No primeiro exemplo faltava uma virgula. Corrigi as duas.

Comment: Obrigado isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

tente `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘YourTable’)` [Veja mais aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: essa minha condição 
 where v.Codigo in(44,45) // campo Codigo os ids são variáveis
 ou seja irei fazer consulta com outros ids

Comment: ja tentou com `RETURNING`? ou `WHERE  v.Codigo = @id_1 OR v.Codigo = @id_2`

Comment: Pode me mostrar um ex